# Upgrading lxc version

Tags: upgrade, lxc

Trying to upgrade the lxc version from 0.7.5 to 0.8.0.
Executed following command :

```
apt-get install lxc
```

But it didnt work the package is still 0.7.5.

```
apt-get install lxc=0.8.0
```

Gives error saying

```
E: Version '0.8.0' for 'lxc' was not found
```

How to upgrade it to next version?
Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Using `apt` to install `lxd` or `lxc` [is no longer recommended](https://docs.conjure-up.io/stable/en/user-manual#install-lxd):

> [Snaps](https://snapcraft.io/) are the recommended installation method. In upcoming Ubuntu releases the snap version of LXD will be the only recommended way of installing and using LXD.

On Ubuntu 16.04, you can install the Snaps version with:

```
sudo snap install lxd
/snap/bin/lxd init
```

If you have existing `lxd` containers, you can migrate them:

```
/snap/bin/lxd.migrate
```

To remove the apt packaged version of `lxc`:

```
sudo apt remove lxc lxc-utils lxcfs liblxc1 liblxc-common lxd lxd-client
sudo apt autoremove
```

To update your bash PATH after removing the apt package type:

```
hash -r
```

Now, you should be using the snap package version of lxc:

```
> which lxc
/snap/bin/lxc
> lxc version
To start your first container, try: lxc launch ubuntu:18.04

Client version: 3.5
Server version: 3.5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try these commands on terminal to update `lxc` package to a newest version,

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-lxc/daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install lxc
```

Comment: Thanks Avinash! But, the version 1.0.0 beta1 (the latest one) has some bugs in it. We need 0.8.0 version. The specific.